# Producing a color map image using Python

Tags: python, c, image

I have a working program in C++ that generates data for a Mandelbrot Set. I am able to get the color map image of the Mandelbrot set using gnuplot. In order to save the image, I just take a screenshot which doesn't give a very accurate image.

how I can use a Python script in order to produce and save the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is the standard means to produce 2D images and image files in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Source code [**Draw a Mandelbrot Set (Python)**](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216851.html#)

PIL and NumPy ofcourse ;)